# Terminal window top bar is hidden after Ubuntu updates applied

Tags: command-line, unity

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, this worked fine until updates applied recently. After that, when opening a terminal it is always parked in the top left of the display and it is unable to be moved. Other applications such as eclipse or Libre Office do not have this problem. In addition if the Unity bar is parked on the left hand side it will cover the terminal window. I have attempted to use Ctrl-Alt-Numpad1,23 etc to manually move the display but only Numpad0 will minimise the terminal. I have also attempted

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel
```

[image: Desktop Image]